# Polymer paper-icon-button doesn't show an image

Tags: html, polymer

I want to make a paper-drawer-panel that has a menu button on the left side that opens the navigation drawer. So in the main header panel I added the button, just like in the Polymer documentation:

```
<paper-header-panel main>
  <paper-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
      <div>Extracurricular Activities</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <!-- main content -->
  </paper-toolbar>
</paper-header-panel>
```

The problem is that the menu button doesn't have an image, but I correctly included the paper-icon-button. When I click on the place where the button should be I can se a normal ripple effect and the drawer opens, so the button must be there.

[Here is a screenshot of the header, the menu button should be at the left of the header text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9IQ9.png)

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the network logs at chrome dev tools?

Comment: Yes, the icon file isn't listed...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure that you also import the icon set. The default icons (including menu) can be found in [iron-icons](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons).

Once you have installed iron-icons. Make the following import:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
```

Comment: Ah, yes. My mistake was that I included iron-icon, not iron-icons. Thank you very much!

Comment: It worked, but paper-button-icon shouldn't import its dependencies itself? i.e. if iron-icons is necessary to use paper-button-icon it should be imported inside the file paper-button-icon.html.

Comment: @Jp_ Normally, elements do import their own dependencies. However, you do not need `iron-icons` necessarily to use `paper-icon-button`, you just need just need some icon set. Importing icon sets that may or may not be used is not very efficient.

Comment: @Maria Including iron-icons.html in index.html works for me. But inside paper-icon-button.html actually includes iron-icons.html as well.  I wonder why it didn't work and we have to include again in index.html.

Comment: @Sam I just checked on [Github](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-icon-button/blob/master/paper-icon-button.html) and I did not see `iron-icons.html` included, only `iron-icon.html`

Comment: This worked for me, too, but gotta say the documentation wasn't clear. [Paper-icon-button](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button) says: `paper-icon-button includes a default icon set`, then shows `icon="menu"` in an example. Then the next line says `See iron-iconset for more information about how to use a custom icon set.` Sounds like `paper-icon-button` _should_ have "menu", if it has a default icon-set, but apparently not...